# Invoice ID Column Null in Credit Memo Table

Tags: mysql, creditmemo, table

Has anybody else noticed that the `invoice_id` column in `sales_flat_creditmemo` is always Null?

The `order_id` column is populated, but nothing in the `invoice_id` column. Is this just me?

Comment: the code is there to set it during the refund function but I cannot seem to figure out when it will/should be triggered. Maybe only for some payment methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I had a quick grep, and in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Creditmemo/Create.php` there's this function

```
public function getHeaderText()
{
   if ($this->getCreditmemo()->getInvoice()) {
       $header = Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Credit Memo for Invoice #%s', $this->getCreditmemo()->getInvoice()->getIncrementId());
   }
   else {
       $header = Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Credit Memo for Order #%s', $this->getCreditmemo()->getOrder()->getRealOrderId());
   }
   return $header;
}
```

This reminded me that there's at least two places you can create a credit memo from, depending on your payment provider.

We use Ebizmarts_Sagepay for most of our orders, and we can create a credit memo from the order, and we can also create a credit memo from the invoice. If we do it from the invoice we'll get the header that says `for Invoice #%s`, if we do it from the order we'll get the header that says `for Order #%s`.

We also use M2E_Pro and on those order we do a credit memo on the invoice. So I'd guess it depends on whether the payment methods supports refunds.